# draw a vertical line in the middle of the block

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks per page

And on the second block, I want to add a vertical line in the middle, the essence of this line is that its height should be equal to the height of the block, and if the height of the block increases, then the line, respectively, too

I'm trying to add such a line, but it does not correspond to the height of the block, but to the height of the page, and is also not located in the block itself..

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 600px;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block2 .scroll-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -0);
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) padding-box,
              linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) border-box;
}

.block3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-line"></div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need it to be an element? It could be just a simple background like this:

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center/2px 100% no-repeat;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to indent the top and bottom specifically for this line? just margin will indent the entire block

Comment: By "indent the top and bottom" do you mean reducing its height? Just reduce the `100%` in that line, it's the background height.